# How can I ignore zoomed mode in app?

Tags: ios, display

View my app:

[image: view in standard mode]

When I turn on Zoomed mode (Setting -> Display -> View), it looks like this:

[image: view in zoomed mode]

How can I ignore zoomed mode in application?

Comment: Why would you ignore it? Write your app correctly so your app displays properly for the given screen size.

Comment: Use this code to detect the zoom and show a informative popup to the user- 


var isZoomed: Bool {
    return UIScreen.main.scale < UIScreen.main.nativeScale
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **no standard way** to ignore this accessibility feature in an application if you are using Auto Layout, and for a good reason: **it is a help for people with physical disabilities**.

Imagine having poor eyesight - having an app that has this useful feature  deliberately disabled would be quite frustrating.

That said, if you have a fully relative layout (so the dimensions of every element on the screen is relative to the screen size), your layout will be more or less unaffected by Zoomed Mode.

Comment: There are programs that look the same in different modes.

Comment: You are missing the point @ratkevich, accessibility is something that apps should support as much as possible.  I suggest you read through some of this: [iOS Accessibility](https://developer.apple.com/accessibility/ios/)

Comment: I don't think the feature is related to accessibility. There are actually 2 kind of zoom, one in accessibility and the other (the one related to this question) is a feature of the display that simply downgrade the resolution and it is available only for some models.  Very annoying, indeed (at least in 2020).

Comment: Pokemon Go seems to be unaffected by this. Where as Swordy Quest is affected: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/swordy-quest-an-rpg-adventure/id1446641513